# Why is joda dateTime giving incorrect month?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I am using joda DateTime to change String to DateTime. But for every month it is changing the month to 01, rest all fields are correct. Can someone point at the issue. Thanks

```
 DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
 DateTime loggedD=format.parseDateTime(logged_date);
 //logged_date= 2016-04-11 12:22:31
 //2016-01-11T12:22:31.000+05:30
```

I have also tried below code but same issue.

```
 DateTime loggedD = DateTime.parse(logged_date,DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DD` is day in year, and I suspect that's causing you issues. I think the month parsing is good but the day setting is setting the day *in the year* and that will set your month too (imagine the 100th day of the year). Try `dd` instead.

[Here's the formatting doc](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html):

> D Day in year Number  189
>
> d Day in month    Number  10

Comment: Correct answer, and I add this explanation: Joda-Time first tries to evaluate the combination of parsed year, month and day-of-month. If this does not succeed (day-of-month is missing) then it evaluates the combination of year and day-of-year IGNORING the month (which is somehow inconsistent). A strict parse would reject such input with the misleading pattern but Joda-Time is (too) tolerant here.